# How do I dynamically find metadata for a Clojure function?

Tags: function, clojure, metadata, clojure-contrib

Say I have the following code:

```
(defn ^{:graph-title "Function 1"} func-1
  [x]
  (do-something-with x))

(defn get-graph-title 
  [func]
  (str
    ((meta func) :graph-title)))
```

I expect this to return "Function 1", but it returns nil.  I think this stems from the following difference, which I don't totally comprehend:

```
(meta func-1)
=>  {:ns some-ns-info, :name func-1}
(meta #'func-1)
=>  {:ns some-ns-info, :name func-1, :graph-title "Function 1"}
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The metadata is attached to the var, not to the function.

Thus, to get the graph title, you have to get the entry `:graph-title` from the meta of the var. How do you like your macros ?

```
(defmacro get-graph-title
  [func]
  `(:graph-title (meta (var ~func))))

(get-graph-title func-1)
=> "Function 1"
```

Comment: Or just use the current definition and do (get-graph-title #'func-1)

Answer (score 36):

There's metadata on the *function* `func-1`, metadata on the *Var* `#'func-1`, and metadata on the *symbol* `'func-1`.  The Clojure reader macro `^` adds metadata to the *symbol*, at read time.  The `defn` macro copies metadata from the *symbol* to the *Var*, at compile time.

Prior to Clojure 1.2, functions did not support metadata.  In Clojure 1.2, they do, and `defn` also copies some standard *Var* metadata to the *function*:

```
Clojure 1.2.0
user=> (defn ^{:foo :bar} func-1 [] nil) 
#'user/func-1
user=> (meta func-1)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name func-1}
user=> (meta #'func-1)
{:foo :bar, :ns #<Namespace user>, :name func-1, ...
```

However, in current Clojure 1.3 snapshots, `defn` does not copy any metadata to the function:

```
Clojure 1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT
user=> (defn ^{:foo :bar} func-1 [] nil) 
#'user/func-1
user=> (meta func-1)
nil
user=> (meta #'func-1)
{:foo :bar, :ns #<Namespace user>, :name func-1, ...
```

In general, if you want to get at the metadata of a definition, you want metadata on the *Var*.

Comment: Leonel's answer was closer to what I was looking for, but thanks for the explanation - clears things up a lot.

Comment: Any known reason why meta is no longer copied to the fn ?

Answer (score 4):

While I wouldn't say this is bullet proof, I'll put it here for prosperity, in case for some reason, you only had the Fn object, and not the symbol or Var for it.

From what I know, when `defn` evaluates, it generates a class with name as per `(munge fn-symbol)`. There is a function called `demunge` which will reverse this for us. Thus, from the class name of a Fn object, we can get the symbol back, and from the symbol, we can find the var back.

```
(-> (class some-fn)
    (print-str)
    (demunge)
    (symbol)
    (find-var)
    (meta))
```

Funnily enough, `demunge` can be found in both `clojure.main` and `clojure.repl`, and they do exactly the same thing, so feel free to require any of them to bring in demunge:

```
(require '[clojure.main :refer (demunge)])
;; or
(require '[clojure.repl :refer (demunge)])
```

WARNING:

As I said prior, first try to just do:

```
(meta #'some-fn)
```

Instead of what I'm showing in this answer, as it is the proper idiomatic mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

The metadata you specify on the *symbol* func-1 in your source code is copied to the *var* named func-1 by the def special form. See the documentation for def in http://clojure.org/special_forms

When you evaluate `func-1` where that's a symbol bound to a var, you get the *value* of the var (which is the function object in this case). See http://clojure.org/vars

The function object itself does not automatically recieve the metadata manually specified on the symbol / var.

So, the information you want is not in the function at all. It's in the var, and you have to specify that you really want the var `func-1` itself instead of its value. That's what (var func-1), and the equivalent short-cut #'func-1 does.