# How to pass the variable name as a string to a function? (ClojureScript)

Tags: metadata, metaprogramming, clojurescript, template-meta-programming

### Description of the situation

I want to make a form template for an element, but they must be dynamically created. The meta data involved in the Component should use the variable-name passed as it's meta-data.

### Code

For example,

In the view,

```clj
(ns my.app
  (:require [my.app.templating :as template])

(defn view-component [nOperacaoExtrato]
    [:<>
      (template/temp-form nOperacaoExtrato)])
```

The templating function,

```clj
(ns my.app.templating)

(defn temp-form
  "Template input"
  [dado]
  #_(js/console.log (str "meta-data: " (meta #'dado)))
  (let [nome-var (:name (meta #'dado))]
    [:div.col
     [:label
      {:for (str "form1_" nome-var)}
      "Natureza do Dispendio"]
     [:p
      {:class "form-control",
       :id (str "form1_" nome-var)
       :name (str "form1" nome-var)}
       dado]]))
```

The result should be, something like this (because the variable passed is `nOperacaoExtrato`):

```clj
       [:div.col
        [:label
         {:for "form1_re-fin-n-operacao-extrato-prop"}
            "Nº da Operação no Extrato"]
          [:p
         {:class "form-control",
          :id "form1_re-fin-n-operacao-extrato-prop",
          :name "form1_re-fin-n-operacao-extrato-prop"}
         (h/preencher-str nOperacaoExtrato)]]
```

### The issue:

Both of these return `null`.

```clj
(meta #'data)
(meta data)
``
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I dynamically find metadata for a Clojure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592306/how-do-i-dynamically-find-metadata-for-a-clojure-function)

Comment: Especially: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5595649/13590263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably convert this function to a macro. Let me show you fellow Portuguese speaker:

src/cljs/user.cljc

```clj
(ns cljs.user)

(defn temp-form-fn
  "Template input"
  [dado nome-var]
  [:div.col
   [:label
    {:for (str "form1_" nome-var)}
    "Natureza do Dispendio"]
   [:p
    {:class "form-control",
     :id (str "form1_" nome-var)
     :name (str "form1" nome-var)}
    dado]])

#?
(:clj
 (defmacro temp-form
   [dado]
   `(temp-form-fn ~dado ~(name dado))))
```

Then in the repl:

```clj
cljs.user> (require '[cljs.user :refer-macros [temp-form]])
nil
cljs.user> (let [nOperacaoExtrato 1234]
             (temp-form nOperacaoExtrato))
[:div.col
 [:label {:for "form1_nOperacaoExtrato"} "Natureza do Dispendio"]
 [:p
  {:class "form-control",
   :id "form1_nOperacaoExtrato",
   :name "form1nOperacaoExtrato"}
  1234]]
```